# Does a detached thread keep its captured shared_ptr alive?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

If I have a shared_ptr that I copy into a std::thread, detach the thread, and then I destroy all other copies of the shared_ptr, can I expect the detached thread to continue to have a live copy of the shared_ptr?
For example if I have:

```
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> my_foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    std::thread soon_detached([my_foo = my_foo]() {my_foo->bar()});
    soon_detached.detach();
}
```

Can I trust that `bar()` is "safe" to call in that situation (in that it won't try to call bar on a Foo that's being destructed/is destructed even if the initial copy of `my_foo` is long out of scope?

Comment: Since you’ve captured by value, you’ve increased the reference counter, which will be decreased again at the end of the lambda’s scope.

Comment: Why do you think detaching the thread could make a difference here?

Comment: @davmac Since we're detaching my understanding was that C++ is passing the lambda on to the OS and we're deleting our own handle to the std::thread at the end of the scope (without the lambda inside necessarily being finished). Since the std::thread is deleted (and I figured the thread would contain the lambda), I was wondering how C++ would know to decrement the reference counter at the end of the lambda?

Comment: Usual warning about detached threads: Be really, really sure this is the behaviour you want. You've ceded all control of the thread and this often ends poorly. If you've already taken steps to mitigate this, groovy. If not, know there there may be steps that need to be taken.

Comment: this looks like it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14148661/4342498.  IMHO the answer is correct in its information.

Comment: @AryanSefidi in my understanding the lambda object itself is copied (actually, moved) when you create the thread object. It will belong however to the underlying thread, not the thread object itself; so, destroying the thread object won't destroy the lambda object, nor the shared_ptr it contains, and neither will detaching the thread.

Comment: Example program to demonstrate. It's a little complicated, and it might help to remove the shared_ptr altogether, so you can see the lifetime of the `foo2` object more clearly: https://godbolt.org/z/1GrsjnxY4

Comment: @davmac Oh wow, thanks! This is pretty much exactly what I needed to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a detached thread keep its captured shared_ptr alive?

Yes. The lambda - and thus also the captures of the lambda - will stay alive as long as the thread is executing. Same would also apply to `args` passed into `std::thread`.

> we're deleting our own handle to the std::thread at the end of the scope

The `std::thread` object won't contain the functor. It will need to be stored in dynamic memory. The lifetime of the executing thread is separate from the lifetime of the `std::thread` wrapper.